# Is it possible to make autocomplete to complete a yasnippet in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, yasnippet

I have configured yasnippet and auto-complete bindings so it won't collide, auto complete uses `<tab>` and yasnippet uses `<backtab>`:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path
              "~/.emacs.d/plugins/yasnippet")
(require 'yasnippet)
(yas-global-mode 1)

;; Remove Yasnippet's default tab key binding
(define-key yas-minor-mode-map (kbd "<tab>") nil)
(define-key yas-minor-mode-map (kbd "TAB") nil)
;; Set Yasnippet's key binding to shift+tab
(define-key yas-minor-mode-map (kbd "<backtab>") 'yas-expand)
```

I created two yasnippets one with the key `lorem_dummy` and the other with the key `lorem_image`, one of the examples:

```
# -*- mode: snippet; require-final-newline: nil -*-
# name: lorem_image
# key: lorem_image
# binding: direct-keybinding
# --
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/${1:width}/${2:height}/${3:$$(yas-choose-value '("abstract" "city" "animals" "food" "people" "transport" "business" "sports" "technics"))}/${4:text}" alt="$3">
```

is it possible to make Emacs auto complete work if I just write lorem and press  to show in a dropdown the two choices ( `lorem_dummy` and `lorem_image` )? Because right now it doesn't come up the yasnippets, but the regular autocomplete does work ( variables and the rest of the stuff ).

-- **update** --

Ok, this is strange, after following the solution in the "duplicated question" link, everything seemed to work perfectly, but then after a few hours it started to behave strange, randomdly, sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't. I made a video showing the problem, it works, then I restart Emacs and stops working again.

[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F-ewuKhMqW4)

Comment: ok, it is a duplicate. I'm sorry but I'm afraid I couldn't find that question when I searched on stackoverflow. Please close or remove this as the one you posted solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Add [`ac-source-yasnippet`](https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete/blob/c4b82a661e058a8ca5f57aaedc4a3cc1041cb742/doc/manual.md#ac-source-yasnippet) to your `ac-sources`, e.g.

```
(eval-after-load "auto-complete"
  '(add-to-list 'ac-sources 'ac-source-yasnippet))
```

Comment: I added that after the `<backtab>` definitions and I got an error:

`Symbol's value as variable is void: ac-sources`

Comment: @Fabman, this only works after `auto-complete` is loaded. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I'm sorry my bad, I added that before activating `'ac-sources` and that's why I got that error.
Anyway, after adding that still won't auto-complete the snippets.

Comment: @Fabman, if you inspect `ac-sources` (e.g. using `C-h v ac-sources RET` or similar), does the value include `ac-source-yasnippet`?

Comment: I'm afraid not, it says `Its value is (ac-source-words-in-same-mode-buffers)`

Comment: @Fabman, are you setting `ac-sources` elsewhere in your config? Are you actually loading `auto-complete` somewhere?

Comment: Sorry Chris, No, I wasn't, I just checked the 'possible duplicate' that you added and that did solved my problem. I guess I didn't searched for the proper words, english is not my first language.

Comment: I don't know if I should add a new question in stackoverflow or if I can continue to ask in this one, after a few hours working right now the autocomplete of yasnippets is not working again, and then it works sometimes, it randomly works, and if I check the ac-sources the yasnippet source hasn't been added to the web-mode, it's very strange.

`(defun add-yasnippet-ac-sources ()
  (add-to-list 'ac-sources 'ac-source-yasnippet))
(add-hook 'web-mode-hook 'add-yasnippet-ac-sources)`

Comment: I made a video, in that video I use a couple of custom snippets, and they work perfectly, and then restart Emacs, try those again and autocomplete won't work with them ( even if they're loaded, because they work if I type them manually ).

[--> video <---](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F-ewuKhMqW4&hd=1)

Comment: @Fabman, please ask a new question.

Comment: ok, thanks, is just that I wasn't quite sure if it was going to be marked as duplicate, because is basically the same question... After the explanation in the new question can I link to this one?